# When do we use switches in cut-through mode?

Tags: networking, ethernet, switching

I'm a computer network undergraduate and now I'm working on a project at university. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: We do not. Modern network switches do switching in hardware (store-and-forward) to achieve wirespeed switching. Cut-through was proposed to speed software switching, but hardware switching became a commodity, obsoleting cut-through switching. Old, obsolete things are often taught, e.g. network address classes that were deprecated in 1993 (almost 30 years ago, but still taught).

Comment: @RonMaupin Cut-through switching is still available on some switches. It reduces the forwarding latency in those switches. I agree that there's not much point with today's interface rates.